# ASP.NET missing formview in local

Tags: c#, asp.net

My **formview** is missing when i run the program locally i don't know what is the problem there is no error or anything else. but when i upload it to IIS it works perfectly fine. what is the cause of this problem? there is no problem in the codes. I think?

Comment: i've tried it so many times